# ListView doesn't show up

Tags: android, listview

I'm working with android
here's my code:

```
public void done(List<ParseObject> colList, ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
          dataList = new ArrayList<String>();   
          for(int counter = 0; counter < colList.size(); counter++)
          {
           String data =  colList.get(counter).getString("name");
           dataList.add(data);
          }
          listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(WardRobeActivity.this, 
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dataList);
          ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
          listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);
       } else {
          Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
       }
```

I'm getting data from the cloud. colList has the data list from the cloud and i'm adding it on the arrayList then set it to the listView adapter what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Cant see anything wrong in the code , could you tell us whats the problem? You get a error ? Or is it just that the list doesnt show up?

Comment: where is your done method fired?

Comment: the listView just doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create listAdapter first and add the `data`.

```
[...]
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);

public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
           listAdapter.add(String.valueOf(colList.size())); //only a Test 
           for(int counter = 0; counter < colList.size(); counter++)
              {
                String data =  colList.get(counter).getString("name");
                if (data == "") 
                  {
                    listAdapter.add("no name");
                  } else {
                    listAdapter.add(data);
                  }
              }
       listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
       [...]
```